# Common-LISP Print function itself

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quine

I want to print ,as described in the title, my whole function.

```
(DEFUN X () ...)

-> (DEFUN X () ...)
```

What do i need to write in "..." ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#1=(defun x () (write '#1# :circle t))
```

Comment: That's quine, but not exact what OP wanted - "a function that prints itself".

Answer (score 1):

### Define a my:defun that records the source

Lars's answer is a clever one, using circular structures to refer to the source within the source.  Another option that might be a bit more useful for general introspection purposes is to define a special variable that provides access to the form being defined. Here's an initial, but not quite polished, version:

```
(defpackage #:introspective-common-lisp
  (:use "COMMON-LISP")
  (:shadow "DEFUN")
  (:nicknames #:icl))

(in-package #:icl)

(defvar *current-form* nil
  "The current form being evaluated (typically a definition form.")

(defmacro defun (&whole form name lambda-list &body body)
  "Like CL:DEFUN, except that within BODY, *CURRENT-FORM* is bound to
the defining ICL:DEFUN form."
  `(cl:defun ,name ,lambda-list 
     (let ((*current-form* ',form))
       ,@body)))

(defun x ()
  "A function that prints its source."
  (print *current-form*))
```

```
CL-USER> (in-package #:icl)
#<PACKAGE "INTROSPECTIVE-COMMON-LISP">
ICL> (x)

(DEFUN X
    NIL
  (PRINT *CURRENT-FORM*)) 
(DEFUN X
    NIL
  (PRINT *CURRENT-FORM*))
```

Remember that `NIL` and `()` are the same thing in Common Lisp, so `(defun x () ...)` is the same as `(defun x nil ...)`.  You could, of course, examine the value of `*current-form*` and decide to print `()` instead, but the point here is that you have access to the form, and you're now free to print it however you want (or do whatever else you want with it).

### Better declaration handling

#### By parsing the body

With Common Lisp's macro facilities, this is actually a pretty easy thing to do, and I was able to cobble this one together in a very short time.  However, there are some subtleties to be aware of.  In this initial version, I expanded the custom `icl:defun` macro to

```
`(cl:defun ,name ,lambda-list 
   (let ((*current-form* ',form))
     ,@body)))
```

This will misplace declarations from `body`, though.  This really needs to be something like:

```
`(cl:defun ,name ,lambda-list 
   ,@(util:body-declarations body)
   (let ((*current-form* ',form))
     ,@(util:body-forms body)))
```

There are packages out there that will parse a body into declarations/docstring and forms, and it's not too hard to roll your own, either.

#### By using &aux variables

You could also skip the `let` altogether, and add in a `&aux` variable to the `cl:defun`'s lambda list, but to do that well, you'd need to check whether there's already an `&aux` keyword in the lambda list, because you wouldn't want to add a redundant one.  This isn't too hard to do, but it does make our code a little bit more complicated:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)

(cl:defun with-aux-variable (lambda-list name &optional value)
  "Returns a new lambda list like LAMBDA-LIST (which should be an
ordinary lambda list), but with an NAME as an &aux variable with the
specified VALUE."
  (let ((tail (if (member '&aux lambda-list)
                  (list (list name value))
                  (list '&aux (list name value)))))
    (append lambda-list tail)))

) ; eval-when

(defmacro defun (&whole form name lambda-list &body body)
  "Like CL:DEFUN, except that within BODY, *CURRENT-FORM* is bound to
the defining ICL:DEFUN form."
  `(cl:defun ,name ,(with-aux-variable lambda-list 
                                       '*current-form*
                                       (list 'quote form))
     ,@body))
```

Comment: Thanks for such an accurate answer :)